# Text in UITextView in UITableViewCell is not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to assign some text to a text view in a custom table cell but for some reason the text is not showing up. I have 2 similar table cells where 1 has image and text and the other just text. The first 1 works without a problem but when assigning the text to the second cell it doesn't work.

> Main Table View Controller

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let imageCheck = tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageNotesData", for: indexPath) as! ImageNotesCell
            cell.notes.text = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
            guard let imageFirebasePath = tableData[indexPath.row]["Image"] else {
                return cell }
            let pathReference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: imageFirebasePath as! String)
            pathReference.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1614 * 1614) { data, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.storedImage.image = image
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notesData", for: indexPath) as! NotesCell
            let noteString = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
            print("NS: ",noteString)
            cell.notes.text = tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"] as! String
            return cell
        }
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(tableData[indexPath.row]["Notes"])
    }
```

> ImageNotesCell.swift
>       import UIKit

```
class ImageNotesCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var storedImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var notes: UITextView!
}
```

> NotesCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class NotesCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var notes: UITextView!
}
```

In the Firebase DB my sample text is "The custom disguises a supreme." When `print("NS: ",noteString)` runs I get `NS:  The custom disguises a supreme.` When I click on the row to trigger `didSelectRowAt` it outputs `Optional(The custom disguises a supreme.)` I'll quadruple check if I connected the outlets but I am sure I did. Not sure where what the problem is.

[image: notesView constraint 1]

[image: notesView contraint 2]

The table view cell height for the custom class notesData is static at 350 for the row height

Comment: can you show the prototype of the `NotesCell`?

Comment: Could you print `cell.notes`, or at least check its frame?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Do you mean the swift file? It is posted above and if not let me know what that is.

Comment: @Larme here is the output cell.notes:  `<UITextView: 0x7fd560083c00; frame = (69.6667 58; 274.667 234); text = 'The custom disguises a su...'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000004440b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000002254a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {274.66666666666674, 33}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>`

Comment: you use static or dynamic height , check constraints for notes textView in notesCell

Comment: When I see the frame with origin being (~70,60), is your cell bigger than that? Use the XCode Debug View Hierarchy to check if it's because your cell is too small: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: I wanted to see the constraints that are used for it.., and attributes of it..

Comment: meaning a screenshot of the storyboards with selected prototype cell and expanded its constraints

Comment: I updated the question with the info (hopefully all of it) captured

Comment: @LampPost why would you use gif, and with such low resolution?

Comment: I honestly thought it would be the best way to show all the information rather than multiple screenshots of the custom cell and the text view. If there is a better way or better yet tell me what should I screenshot would be great.

Comment: zoom to the constraints of the contentView notes cell and screenshot it , also do you use dynamic height cells or static ????

Comment: I wanted to see constrains laid upon the textView.. look at the gif and try to read those.. or anything else.. it's just too fast.. that's not the way how to share it.. best would be a working minimal example.. second best is not to use storyboards because then you can just copy paste the code.. third is a screenshot of the constraints..

Comment: Ok I removed the gif because it's low quality doesn't help. Also I just started so I am not too comfortable with using code to creating the layouts just yet. Hopefully this the SS is what you are looking for. I also really do appreciate the help.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I connected it by dragging the the textView outlet to the notes outlet in the NotesCell.swift file. The cell is has the custom class NotesCell, the style is Custom and the Identifier is notesData